# Troubleshooting httpd in Linux

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, networking, unix, httpd

I have a small personal site hosted on Unix (using a common hosting account).

My experience with Unix is limited (too bad). Recently I set up a httpd server running on port 8082 (not Apache - but an Apache server is already running on port 80 by default). It appears to be running (judging from the "ps" output).
I thought that I would be able to get web pages from this httpd server in the URL `www.mysite.com:8082/test`... but I don't.

I don't know what is going wrong, and worse, I don't know what to look for! Maybe I am overlooking something trivial?

Any help will be very welcome!

Comment: You are running on port 8082 and trying to open an url in port 8080? is this correct or was a typo?

Comment: Might be a firewall at the hosting provider - 80 is well-known port for http, 8080 (or 8082?) might be blocked.

Answer (score 1):

You said "running on port 8082" then you said "www.mysite.com:8080/test".  If you're running on port 8082, then you have to specify port 8082, not port 8080.

I find the unix command "HEAD" (not "head", so this doesn't work on Mac OS X) very helpful in debugging web problems.  Or just learn how to telnet to the port and issue http commands.

```
   telnet localhost 8082
   GET / http/1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at the log files of your webserver?
Perhaps the access or error log has something useful to report.

Answer (score 0):

Also check to make sure there's not a firewall outside the server or iptables.

Check locally with

```
iptables -nL
```

Or

```
fctl -sr
```

if your'e using a BSD variant with pf.

Answer (score 0):

Check the server log files ?